# Spark 2.1 PySpark Bug: sc.textFile("test.txt").repartition(2).collect()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Using a vanilla text file:

```
echo "a\nb\nc\nd" >> test.txt
```

Using the vanilla spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz, the following fails. The same test works fine with older versions of Spark:

```
$ bin/pyspark

Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Dec 18 2016 07:03:39)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.

>>> sc.textFile("test.txt").collect()
[u'a', u'b', u'c', u'd']

>>> sc.textFile("test.txt").repartition(2).collect()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/admin/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 810, in collect
    return list(_load_from_socket(port, self._jrdd_deserializer))
  File "/Users/admin/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/rdd.py", line 140, in _load_from_socket
    for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):
  File "/Users/admin/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 529, in load_stream
    yield self.loads(stream)
  File "/Users/admin/opt/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/serializers.py", line 524, in loads
    return s.decode("utf-8") if self.use_unicode else s
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Using the vanilla Spark 2.1 local installation, same text file, but the Scala-based spark-shell, the exact same commands work:

```
$ bin/spark-shell

Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> sc.textFile("test.txt").collect()
res0: Array[String] = Array(a, b, c, d)

scala> sc.textFile("test.txt").repartition(2).collect()
res1: Array[String] = Array(a, c, d, b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug. It will be fixed post Spark 2.1

**UPDATE**: Confirmed fixed in Spark 2.1.1

Answer (score 0):

In the local installation you are using Scala while you are using python in your first test.

With python, see the answer of @mariusz https://stackoverflow.com/a/40780017/3090365

Comment: The test errors in Python and works in Scala. I know that. I pointed that out. I need to help get the Python version working. I don't think the linked post has anything to do with my issue. The pyspark example works fine in Spark 2.0.2