# Spark not using all available cores on a Node in Standalone Cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I'm running a small cluster with a separate 1 Master and 1 Slave node (with 8 VCores). I launch the cluster via  `/sbin/start-all.sh` and then add pyspark to it with `/bin/pyspark --master spark://<master ip>:7077`

now in the webui everything seems OK I got my worker registered with the master and I have 8 Cores available. Also the pyspark shell also got all 8 cores.

I have a small RDD consisting of 14 rows each row containing a string pointing to a compressed text file.

```
def open_gzip(filepath):

    with gzip.open(filepath, 'rb') as f:
        file_content = f.read()
    return file_content.split(b'\r\n')

wat_paths_rdd = sc.textFile('./file.paths')
wat_rdd = wat_paths_rdd.flatMap(open_gzip)
```

now when I try to run this code, I can see in `htop` that on my worker node only 2 cores are utilized when `flatMap` is invoked.

The following parameters I have tried to set on both slave and master with no avail:

```
in /conf/spark-defaults.conf
spark.cores.max 8
spark.executor.cores 8

even though I can set
spark.executor.memory 14500m

in /conf/spark-env.sh
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=8
```

I'm a bit at a lose here in my previous config, where I ran everything off one machine and `spark.cores.max 8` was enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of cores are utilised based on number of tasks which are dependent on number of partitions of your rdd. Please check

```
rdd.getNumPartitions
```

If they are 2, then you need to increase number of partitions 2-3 times the number of cores using

```
rdd.repartition
```

or in the start when you parallelize your file.

Comment: thanks I think this would work but sadly there is a bug in spark 2.1. (maybe also the reason why I only have two partions in the first place) that makes repartitioning a read text file impossible for more read here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42844207/spark-2-1-pyspark-bug-sc-textfiletest-txt-repartition2-collect)

Comment: Just tried it with a path list and it works like a charm no need for `rdd.repartition`

Comment: bug is fixed in  spark 2.1.1 [link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-19872)

Comment: In addition to that, make sure that: spark.executor.memory * cores <= Total memory available on every worker. I had one worker that didn't use all its cores because of that.